# How to handle derived classes featuring different parameters

Tags: c#, for-loop, switch-statement

I am new to C# and I have a project in which I have a parent class `Task` with derived classes `FixedTask` and `RelativeTask`.

`FixedTask` and `RelativeTask` have different properties, named differently. And I need to perform some computations with each `Task` to compute some workload.

A `Project` contains different `Tasks` which can be of the various types e.g. `FixedTask` and `RelativeTask`. I was planning on doing something like this:

```
foreach (Task Task in this.Tasks)
{
    switch (Task)
    {
        case FixedTask:
            switch (Task.Frequency)
            {
                case "Daily":
                    // do some calculations
                 
                // other frequency cases
            }
        // other Task cases
    }
```

But I receive an error that `Task` does not have a particular parameter because it is implemented in `FixedTask` but not in `RelativeTask`.

I would have though that the `switch` pattern allowed C# to understand which type he has to consider but apparently not.

What is the proper way of achieving what I want?

Comment: If `FixedTask` and `RelativeTask` are different why do you store them in the same collection? If they, however, have a lot in common, may be you should use `virtual` methods, properties to use a common method(s)?

Comment: It's maybe the question to ask. I am new to C#, I know OOP concepts but have never truly made an application using such language. I come from Python which is much more permissive. They are different in the sense that one has a fixed duration i.e. a `Duration` property and one depends on the project duration and has therefore a `coefficient` property. Therefore, calculations of the workload for each kind of task differ but they are both Tasks hence why I grouped in the first place. It makes sense from a human brain perspective but maybe it's wrong from a OOP perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern matching: `case FixedTask f`.

But you shouldn't. Your base class should not know nor care how the derived classes are implemented.

The purpose of OO and inheritance is that derived classes contain their own logic. So if your task runner wants to execute a task, do so:

```
foreach (Task task in this.Tasks)
{
    task.Execute();
}
```

And then each Task-deriving class has the logic in their overridden `Execute()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching helps:

```
foreach (Task Task in this.Tasks)
        {
            switch (Task)
            {
                case FixedTask ft:
                    switch (ft.Frequency)
                    {
                        case "Daily":
                        ...
                    }
                case RelativeTask rt:
                    switch (rt.OtherProperty)
                    {
                        case ...:
                    }
```

Comment: Technically correct, but bad design. These differences should be handled in the different derived classes.

Comment: @BenedictvonHeyl No, not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick (but not the best) amendment, I suggest *pattern matching*, i.e.

```
foreach (Task task in Tasks) {
  if (task is FixedTask fixedTask) {
    // From now on you work with fixedTask
    switch (fixedTask.Frequency) {
      ...
    }
  } 
  else if (task is RelativeTask relativeTask) {
    // From now on you work with relativeTask
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler that Task is actually a FixedTask.

```
....

   case FixedTask:
        switch (((FixedTask)Task).Frequency)
        {
            case "Daily":
....
```

This will cast the Task to a FixedTask, there are several other wayt to accomplish the same - take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions that provides some further details